# Selectively remove preprocessor directives using Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn, preprocessor, roslyn-code-analysis

I want to use Roslyn to clean the code of some of the older preprocessor directives.

For example, from this code

```
#define TEST_1_0
#define TEST_1_1
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class TypeName
{   
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
#if TEST_1_0
        int TEST_1_0 = 1;
#if TEST_1_1
        int TEST_1_1 = 1;
#else//TEST_1_1
        int TEST_1_1 = 0;
#endif//TEST_1_1
#else//TEST_1_0
        int TEST_1_0 = 0;
#endif//TEST_1_0
    }
}
}
```

I'd like to remove else//TEST_1_0, but keep the else//TEST_1_1. I cannot count on the comments, so I should related a #if with its corresponding #else, if there is one.

Finding the #if is easy, but finding the corresponding #else is less easy.

I tried two strategies:

1. Here i lookup  #else//TEST_1_0 in the analyzer, and create a codefix for that location
2. Here I just create a codefix for #if TEST_1_0 in analyzer, and try to get to the corresponding else from the CodeFixprovider

Both get quite complicated quickly, it seems problematic that directives are trivia, which are spread out over the leadingTrivia of different SyntaxTokens. Changes in the code affect the location directives around quite a bit so it looks like lots of work to program all cases..

Am I missing something? Is there an easier way to do this without programming all the different cases by hand?

Would you go for strategy 1 or 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I concluded that roslyn is not the way to go here.

Roslyn models preprocesessor directives as trivia in the syntax tree, and the location of trivia has great variation depending on the structure of the actual code.

Therefore working on the syntax tree introduces lookup complexities that are not an issue when working text based, and more complexity means more RISK. Binaries should be the same before/after processing!

So I chose to abandon Roslyn and simply parse the code/directive mix as text, using regex to parse and the good-old stack to handle the directive logic.

Now it's much easier, even a piece of cake .. 
Still need to handle some encoding issues, then I'm done! :)
Happy parsing!

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Arjan - Roslyn in not usable for the task. To solve a similar task I made my own simple C# preprocessor tool based on regexp and Python sympy library: [undefine](https://github.com/gaDZella/undefine). I believe it would be helpful for you. As for the task you described, try the following command:

`>> python undefine apply -d TEST_1_0 YourFile.cs`

Comment: Generally, links to a tool or library [should be accompanied by usage notes, a 
specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, or some 
sample code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605), or if possible all of the above.

Comment: As for the task you described, try the following command:
>> python undefine -d TEST_1_0 YourFile.cs

Comment: Please edit it into the answer Comments are not permanent. I'm not asking for myself, but for the benefit of future readers, and for your benefit (so that the answer won't be deleted).

Comment: Thanks, is the following addon sufficient? The full tool usage description is provided on the github project page.

Comment: It looks OK to me, but that's just 1 opinion :)